# Can not use contrller in $stateProvider.state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

app.js :

```
var testRoute= angular.module('testRoute', ['ui.router']);

testRoute.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home/partial-home.html',
            controller: 'myController'
        })

        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'about/partial-about.html'
        });

});
```

I've defined a controller ready and I want to use that controller in each state, but it does not work and I got an error message. How can I use the controller?

Comment: please tell the error which you are getting..

Comment: I got the error : Argument 'myController' is not. I don't know why.

Comment: So you did not create a "myController" method so far in your app?

Comment: I've created a "myController" method in my app ready in controller and I named it "myController".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register myController as a controller, not just have it as a function. So if you have:

```
function myController($scope) {
  ...
}
```

You will need to say:

```
testRoute.controller('myController', myController);
```

Or you can also simply do it inline,

```
testRoute.controller('myController', function($scope) {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Yes, I've registered the controller ready in myController.js and I want to use this controller in state, but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/u7p0UD5mblkQBE5o54LU?p=preview)

```
var testRoute= angular.module('testRoute', ['ui.router']);

testRoute.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'myController'
        })

    $stateProvider.state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'about/partial-about.html'
        });

});

var myController = function($scope){
 alert("hello world!");
}

testRoute.controller('myController', myController);
```

Comment: Thank you that give me that demo